# Selecting in Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, syntax

I'm writing a regex to find code like this:

```
if condition:True:
    statements
```

Where the first colon is instead of `==`.
I've come up with this so far: `r"(if|elif) .* : .* :\n\t"`
But I want to find a way to select the first `:` and replace it with `==`. The thing is, I cant find a way to use regex to substitute `:` without inadvertantly a: replacing the whole `if condition` etc with `==` by writing a

```
re.sub(r"(if|elif) .* : .* :\n\t","==",text)
```

or b: Replacing every colon in my script with `==`, which will cause an Error like

```
NameError: Expected a ':', received '=='
```

So, is there a way to substitute only a bit of the regex with `==`, or is there another way to do this that I overlooked??

**What should happen**
Input:

```py
if 3+4:7:
     print("Three plus four is actually seven")
elif 3+6:10:
    print("3+4 is not 7, yet 3+6=10")
```

Console:
`Three plus four is actually seven`

This is Python 3 by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try matching everything from `if` or `elif` upto last-but one `:` into a match-group and similarly everything after that to the last `:` into another group. Now you can substitute the first match followed by `==` and then the next match

```
re.sub('((?:if|elif)[^:]*):([^:]*:)', r'\1 == \2', s)
```

Comment: Only improvement I can think of is to do `[^:]*` instead of `.*`, so it doesn't match more colons than it should in case some line should happen to have 3 (for some other odd reason). Generally one should try to avoid using `.*` if it's possible.

Comment: @melwil. I thought of doing it, but then it would wrongly stop on the colon incase the expression contains colons

Comment: If the expression contains more colons than the example, there's no guarantee this regex would substitute that correctly anyway. My point is that this regex can actually ignore what little pattern you actually have to match on. Using the negated expression brings in another interesting thing with the fact that it matches newlines, though, so you'd need to turn on multiline and match the end of line with `$`. Your original regex would probably do just fine.

Comment: `re.sub('((?:if|elif)[^:]*):([^:]*:)', '\\1 == \\2', text)` the last `:` must be inside the group

Comment: I did a quick test and it seemed to work `re.sub(r'((?:if|elif) .*):(.*):', r'\1 == \2', "if bool(s.split(':')):True:\n         statements")`. But just to make sure, it would always work, I have updated my answer to anchor the regex with a `$` and set `re.M` flag

Comment: @ShanavasM. Thanks. Updated the answer

Comment: No need for the anchor and flag unless you use the negated colon `[^:]` group instead of the dot. `.` does not match newlines without the dotall (s) flag.

Comment: I am talking about the case where the expression would contain a `:`

Comment: There's no guarantee you can make for that with such a simple regex. People can write truly horrible code :D `re.sub(r'((?:if|elif) .*):(.*:)\s*$', r'\1 == \2', "if 'this text has : in it'[14]:':':", flags=re.M)` -- Not even negated classes are enough here, you need to ignore strings and such as well. The original regex would probably solve the issue which was first posted, and we could build forever to try and solve every case.

Comment: @melwil. Ok I give up.. I realize that it is impossible to make it work with all possibilities where a `:` can occur in the expression. Will revert back the answer and make sure it uses `[^:]*`. Thanks for your patience

Comment: What the negation does for you is to at least just ignore those it can not solve, and you have to solve those in another way. But they may be edge cases, so might not even be worth solving with regex. At some point complexity is no longer worth the effort to automatize and you just have to find and correct those manually. Don't try to hammer a screw because it looks kind of like a nail.